# Django - Celery - missing required positional argument - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delay'

Tags: django, celery

When I define a task with parameters, I get the error:

```
missing 1 required positional argument
```

Though, I'm not sure if it really is missing one. I am passing the argument in `delay` in `views.py`.
I tried defining the task without any arguments and it says:

```
NoneType' object has no attribute 'delay'
```

Besides, when I run a celery worker, it recognizes the task:

```
[tasks]
  . posts.tasks.say_hello_task
```

Why is this happening?

celery.py:

```py
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "zwitter.settings")

app = Celery("zwitter")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

settings.py:

```py
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_RESULT_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "rpc://"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://"
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = timedelta(days=1)
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

tasks.py:

```py
@shared_task
def say_hello_task(name):
    print(f"hello {name}")
```

views.py:

```py
tasks.say_hello_task().delay("john")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `say_hello_task()` function returns `None`. While calling `tasks.say_hello_task().delay("john")`, you are effectively running the function in the current process and calling `.delay` on `None`, as evident from the error. As @mamareza pointed out, you have to call `say_hello_task.delay("john")`.

`app.send_task` is quite useful when you want dependencies of your services minimal. Internally `.delay` infers the task_name from decorated function, serialises with arguments and sends over your RabbitMQ queue for execution in a different process. While also running celery, run in either `DEBUG` or `INFO` mode to see all the logs it emits.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the `()` in @mamareza 's answer. I get it now! Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
tasks.say_hello_task().delay("john")
```

you can import task directly and call it like :

```
say_hello_task.delay("john")
```

**or**

you can call the task by name

```
@shared_task(name='say_hello_task')
def say_hello_task(name):
  print(f"hello {name}")
```

like this:

```
app.send_task(name="say_hello_task", args=("john",))
```

Comment: Importing it directly doesn't seem to be the problem. Though I tried it and it didn't work. I also tried your second solution but it didn't work either. It doesn't raise any errors. But the task still doesn't run.

Comment: your problem was  `missing 1 required positional argument` and that's because of using empty parenthesis. 

Not triggering the task is another problem and there might be misconfiguration